# SharePoint Online, how to disable new "Comments" feature?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, comments

Anyone know how to turn this OFF?

I use my own field to track comments in our document approval system, this new feature confuses users.

This icon appears in custom lists:

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS: And what is this?

Comment: I have opened a new idea at SharePoint User Voice to [enable or disable comments on list items in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/42287590-comments-on-list-item-in-sharepoint-online), please upvote for this idea to get it applied soon.

Comment: Thank You @MohamedEl-QassasMVP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new feature released by Microsoft and currently rolling out in SharePoint Online tenants.

You can find more details about it at: [All you need to know about Commenting in Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/all-you-need-to-know-about-commenting-in-lists/).

Currently it is not possible to disable it at site or list level. But you can disable it at tenant level as given below:

**Solution**:

You can disable comments in SharePoint online lists using PowerShell.

Use below command:

```
Set-SPOTenant -CommentsOnListItemsDisabled $true
```

> **-CommentsOnListItemsDisabled**
>
> Disables or enables commenting functionality on list items. PARAMVALUE: `$true` | `$false`

**Microsoft documentation**: [Set-SPOTenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant)

**Note**: You must be a **SharePoint Administrator** or **Global Administrator** in your tenant to disable this feature using PowerShell.

**Reference**: [How to Enable/Disable the commenting in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/how-to-enable-disable-the-commenting-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)

---

**Update**:

Enable/Disable list comments at SharePoint **list level** will be available very soon. Check detailed information at: [Enable/Disable the comments for a SharePoint Online/Microsoft List](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/05/23/enable-disable-the-comments-for-a-sharepoint-online-microsoft-list/).

Comment: Hi @Ganesh Sanap! Don't You know - is this tenant-level command? What if I need to disable for particular list only?..

Comment: Thank You much for response!

Comment: When I try to run the above PowerShell script, it gives me a below error:
```
Set-SPOTenant -CommentsOnListItemsDisabled $true
``` > Set-SPOTenant : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CommentsOnListItemsDisabled'.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint Online PowerShell you are using? Try updating it to latest version and then execute this command.

Comment: I ran the script using latest powershell , it executes without any error. but still I can see the Command option in Custom list. any clue?

Comment: It may take some time to update the tenant level settings. try checking it after some time.

Comment: Enable/Disable list comments at SharePoint **list level** will be available very soon. Check detailed information in [this article](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/05/23/enable-disable-the-comments-for-a-sharepoint-online-microsoft-list/)